# Error with a code

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

startInfo.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\rundll32.exe";

startInfo.Arguments = 
@"C:\WINDOWS\System32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\c.jpg"
```

I want to specify the image URI `(C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\c.jpg)` as a string variable.So what changes do I have to make in startInfo.Arguments.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: Seriously consider writing a better title for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Construct it before hand then.

```
string imagePath = "C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\c.jpg"; // or get this value from however you please
string arguments = string.Format("C:\WINDOWS\System32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen {0}", imagePath);
startInfo.Arguments = arguments;
```

Comment: I tried this but the photo viewer does not open.Do u any other solution?I need it urgently.